# RTKQuery streaming, how to limit cache entries?

Tags: rtk-query

So I implemented a websocket using this pattern https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates

it works fine but my issue is that I would like to limit the total entries to 30 (websocket is sending a lot, and fast).
I would need a queue like FIFO to keep my list updated but limited.
What would be the pattern to do that , how should I write it ?

EDIT:

I came up with the solution same you suggested, do you think this implementation is ok? (actually it works very well)

```
const currentCache = getCacheEntry();
if(currentCache.data && currentCache.data.ids.length === MAX_ENTRY) {
    const toRemove = currentCache.data.ids[0]
    nearTxAdapter.removeOne(draft, toRemove);
}
nearTxAdapter.addOne(draft, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you `.push()` an item into the array in `updateQueryResults`, check if length is now over 30 and also call `.unshift()` on the array?

You don't need any special tools for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

phry direction is the right one , here is a working implementation example:

```
lastTransferTxSocket.on('token-tx', (tx) => {
    const data:TokenTxInterface = JSON.parse(tx);
    updateCachedData((draft) => {
        const currentCache = getCacheEntry();
        if(currentCache.data && currentCache.data.ids.length === MAX_ENTRY) {
            const toRemove = currentCache.data.ids[0]
            tokenTxAdapter.removeOne(draft, toRemove);
        }
        tokenTxAdapter.addOne(draft, data);
    })
})
```